# Why does the "echo" statement support outputting multiple arguments in a single line and the "echo" function does not?

Tags: php, output, echo, php-5.6

In PHP you can output multiple arguments at once with the `echo` **statement** like this:

```
echo "Mangoes", " ", "are", " ", "tasty.";
```

When you try to do the same with the `echo` **function** like this:

```
echo("Mangoes", " ", "are", " ", "tasty.");
```

You get a error, why is this so?
Could this be because PHP wants you to use string concatenation instead of multiple arguments?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) is not a function. The docs clearly state this:

> echo is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
>   are not required to use parentheses with it. echo (unlike some other
>   language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
>   always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
>   to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters must not be
>   enclosed within parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for your time & help, I appreciate it, +1.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `echo()` its mean you call the function of `echo()`. The echo just has one parameter `echo(_string_)`. SO when you include the , sign in the bracket of echo parameter, so it means you make echo function has more than one parameter. So you are not allowed to do like this `echo("Mangoes", " ", "are", " ", "tasty.");`

Please see this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_echo.asp

Comment: `echo` is not a function, it accepts a list of expressions, not function arguments. If it were a function, it would work with parentheses and multiple arguments in them (and w3schools is wrong - no surprise there).

Comment: Thank you for your time & help, I appreciate it, +1.